# Parse through text files, and grab words in between unique words, using python

Tags: python, parsing

I am trying to build a parser that will go through some SQL scripts and grab the data fields, tables etc. being used. I started it by trying to grab the field names.
The SQL scripts all have a basic structure of:

```
select x,y,z,.. from table # sometimes it will be sel instead of select
```

This occurs usually multiple times in any script.

I have setup the below python code:

```
import csv
import re

def parser():                                     

           f=open('Book1.txt','r')
           data = f.read()
           print re.findall('sel.*from',data)
```

I am only getting one of the select statements through this. Why is this not giving me all the texts between my select statements from which I can then parse through and determine the data fields being used? Maybe there is a better way to do this but I am hitting a wall.

Comment: Do you want to skip sub-selects, or capture them too? Can "sel" and "from" ever occur as part of some identifier, or can you be sure that they only occur as key words?

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is probably matching multiple select statements because it's working in greedy mode. Try using `re.findall('sel.*?from', data)` instead.